# Python sub-process coverage on Travis

Tags: python, travis-ci, coverage.py

I've seen a couple of articles on the subject, but none seem to work for me.

**The case**

A Python package with tests based on `unittest`, `pytest` as test runner and plugins like `pytest-cov` to support the `coverage`. All works fine locally, all tests are executed and pass, coverage is calculated for all tests, including CLI tests using `subprocess.check_output`.

- The project: [github.com/barseghyanartur/valuta](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/valuta)
- Travis generated coverage report: [travis-ci.org/github/barseghyanartur/valuta/jobs/771949032](https://travis-ci.org/github/barseghyanartur/valuta/jobs/771949032)
- Coverage report generated locally: [gist.github.com/barseghyanartur/061a7b88747e3af40c9e862abc0e49bb](https://gist.github.com/barseghyanartur/061a7b88747e3af40c9e862abc0e49bb)

**The issue**

Somehow, on Travis side, coverage is not calculated for the CLI tests. No matter what I do, no matter where and how many times I do include `coverage.pth` or `sitecustomize.py` ([read more about it here](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/subprocess.html)), coverage for CLI is not included.

**The obvious question**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a recap of what was done to solve it (for the folks that may need the answer) the issue was on my configuration of `tox` to blame.

**Before (did not work well, although tests passed)**

```
[testenv]
# Some other config above this line
commands =
    pytest
```

**After (where I got it really to the 100% covered)**

```
[testenv]
# Some other config above this line
commands =
    coverage erase
    pip install -e .
    pytest
```

The `pip install -e .` is obviously the key here.